# Why does my site's slider work properly only on Mac (same browser)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have an slider on which there is a form that allows users to input their phone number so they can get a link sent to their device once a button is clicked.

The drop down allows users to select their phone carrier (AT&T, Verizon ,etc). Using a MAC, via Chrome browser I am able to see the drop down and select items in the browser .

On Windows OS, using the same Chrome browser, not only can I not see what is fully on the drop down (already selected without opening it), but it appears totally empty unless you scroll over it.

[image: This is an image of opening and scrolling on the drop down on a Chrome browser, Windows OS.]

[image: This is an image of opening and scrolling on the drop down on Chrome Browser, Mac OS.]

Here is the form :

```
    <div class="banner-form" id="banner-form1">Enter your number and select your carrier below to   receive a download link !<br />
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">    
    <input type="text" name="keywords" id="keywords" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Mobile   number (ex. 555-555-5555)';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Mobile number (ex. 555-555-5555)') this.value='';" value="Your Number [ex. 100 200 3000] (No dash)" alt="Mobile number (ex. 555-555-5555)" style="color: black;"><br />
    <div id="carrierSelection">
       <select name="carrier" style="font">
       <option value="@vtext.com">Verizon</option>
       <option value="@txt.att.net">AT&amp;T</option>
       <option value="@messaging.sprintpcs.com">Sprint</option>
       <option value="@tmomail.net">T-Mobile</option>
    </select> 
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="carrierButton" id="chbutton" value="Text yourself the app link" />

    </form>
```

Please let me know what your thoughts are, what areas i should be looking at, and what your suspicions are. Any help is greatly, greatly, appreciated. Thank you in advance !

Comment: What is that `style="font"` doing there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that your font color in select list is black (not white)

You now have:

```
<select name="carrier" style="font">
```

Which is false styling.. try:

```
<select name="carrier" style="color: #000">
```

That gives black color for select element text. I'm 100% sure this is font color issue.